# Thread блокирует UI

Tags: потоки-данных, android, многопоточность, java

У меня есть поток который я запускаю из главного-мейн-потока :

```
recalculationThread.start();
```

Данный поток использует мой класс Runnable. Беда в том что когда я запускаю этот поток, весь доступ к UI блокируется. Как быть?

Я знаю о `Handler`, `AsyncTask`, `runOnUIThread` и `post`, `postDelayed`. Есть ли способ,обойтись без них?

Comment: Кто знает, что там внутри Вашего класса.

Comment: а `recalculationThread.start()` - это вызов `Thread.start()` или он переопределен?

Comment: Нужно больше контекста, что бы понять, что не так...     
Приведите больше кода

Comment: Скорее всего проблема у автора могла быть из-за Join()

Answer (score 2):

1. Если в `recalculationThread` есть цикл - имеет смысл поставить внутри цикла `Thread.sleep` чтобы остальные потоки могли "дышать" во время выполнения вашего треда.
2. Поиграйте с приоритетами треда `Thread.setPriority()`

Comment: sleep внутри... может, но вряд ли.

Скорее всего, там блок синхронизации выставлен один на все.

Comment: Пока есть пустой цикл `while(true)` В нём поток каждые 1000мс "засыпает".